# Informar ao usuário que o cadastro já existe

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho um código de realizar o cadastro do usuário no meu site, ele vê que o usuário já é cadastrado e não insere de novo na tabela, mas não consigo informar o usuário que o cadastro já existe.

```
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO usar (campo1, campo2) VALUES (?,?)';


  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);


  if(!$stmt){
      echo 'erro na consulta: '. $conn->error .' - '. $conn->error; 
  }
    $var1 = $_POST['campo1'];
    $var2 = $_POST['campo2'];


    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $var1, $var2);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cadastro realizado com sucesso.');window.location.href='cadastro.php';</script>";
```

Comment: Faz um select antes de dar o insert, veja se o email que ele tentou cadastrar já existe no banco, se o retorno for verdadeiro você informa o usuario que o email ja existe...

Comment: Já tentei, mas mesmo assim não vai

Comment: Algum campo é unique key, o email por exemplo.

Comment: E como eu mudo isso?

Comment: Como é que vê?/Onde está a parte do código que ele vê que o usuário já é cadastrado?

Comment: Gente, obrigada pela atenção, mas eu acho que resolvi. Vou postar a resposta pra vocês verem e se tiver algo de errado, se possível, me informar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi assim:

```
  $var1 = $_POST['campo1'];
  $var2 = $_POST['campo2'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM usar WHERE campo1 = '$var1' AND campo2 = '$var2'";

      $querySelect = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) > 0) {
          echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cadastro existente.');window.location.href='cadastro.php';</script>";
        }

  $sql = 'INSERT INTO usar (campo1, campo2) VALUES (?,?)';


  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);


  if(!$stmt){
      echo 'erro na consulta: '. $conn->error .' - '. $conn->error; 
  }
    $var1 = $_POST['campo1'];
    $var2 = $_POST['campo2'];


    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $var1, $var2);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cadastro realizado com sucesso.');window.location.href='cadastro.php';</script>";
```

Comment: E não foi isso que foi dito no comentário do  Darlei Fernando Zillmer ?? Mas acho que ainda vai continuar inserindo novamente mesmo cadastro. Faltou vc colocar um else para realizar o cadastro.

Comment: Exatamente. Consegui resolver com a resposta dele. Tem algum jeito de colocar ou mencionar ele na resposta? Eu nao sei mexer muito aqui ainda